# What's wrong with my plupload implementation?

Tags: files

For reasons that are out of scope here I should not send packets over 32 MB, so my php.ini looks like this:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 500M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; Its value may be 0 to disable the limit. It is ignored if POST data reading
; is disabled through enable_post_data_reading.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 32M
```

I know [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) can do this, so I "only" needed to integrate it with Drupal. For this I installed [Plupload integration module](https://drupal.org/project/plupload). Thanks to Clive I found [this bug report](https://drupal.org/node/1565930):

> Right now you need to spesify a max file size larger than the max post size as plupload is stil honoring the setting.

I'm not particularly happy with `upload_max_filesize = 500M` but I guess for now I can live and work with it.

I tried custom code first:

```
  'DownloadFile' => array(
    //'#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#type' => 'plupload',
    '#title' => t("Download"),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',

    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array(),
      'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('my_max_file_size', 300 * 1024 * 1024)),
    ),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://mymodule/download',
    '#default_value' => $item->fid,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#plupload_settings' => array(
      'runtimes' => 'html5',
      'chunk_size' => '10mb',
    ),
  ),
```

It was showing 300MB under the Form API field all right. Sadly, everything over 20MB gave me:

> Error: File too large: Some_182MB_file.zip

So I thought I'm doing something wrong and decided to try ready-made solution. I went for [FileField Sources Plupload](https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources_plupload) - I see 32 MB on the node add form, but **182 MB file uploaded all right.**

So what's wrong with my implementation? I practically copied [example from official documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1647890) so I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [Plupload integration module](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) in custom code, you need to set up size twice. Preferably to the same value. First place you do it is the usual:

```
'#upload_validators' => array(
  'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('my_max_file_size', 300 * 1024 * 1024)),
),
```

This handles display and post-upload verification.

Second place is `#plupload_settings`:

```
'#plupload_settings' => array(
  'runtimes' => 'html5',
  'chunk_size' => '10mb',
  'max_file_size' => variable_get('my_max_file_size', 300 * 1024 * 1024) . 'b',
),
```

This is what actually goes to the plupload JavaScript.