# How to save file uploaded with plupload integration module, and make it managed?

Tags: files

As described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/108547/16495), I can use [Plupload integration](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) module to upload my files to server. They go there, I can see them in temp directory, and that's the point I'm stuck.

Code I'm using for a field is:

```
'DownloadFile' => array(
  '#title' => t("Download's download"),
  '#title_display' => 'invisible',
  '#type' => 'file',

  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array( /* extensions */ ),
    'file_validate_size' => array(variable_get('max_size', 300 * 1024 * 1024)),
  ),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://mymodule/download',
  '#plupload_settings' => array(
    'runtimes' => 'html5',
    'chunk_size' => '10mb',
    'max_file_size' => variable_get('max_size', 300 * 1024 * 1024) . 'b',
  ),
),
```

In form validation function I get thus in `$form_state['values']`:

[image: Screenshot]

Since the Views for Drupal 7 got reasonably stable, I was using Drupal 7 and managed files. I have literally no idea how should I take this file and plug it into managed table for other functions to use. As you can see from the time difference, it been some time between the moment I was able to upload and now - all this time with no idea. Tried to treat it as `'#type' => 'file'`, but functions for unmanaged don't get it. They require specific name and even if I add `'#name'` to plupload form element, it still fails.

Is there any way to add file to managed table knowing it's location in `temporary://`?

Comment: I found this answer useful when I had a similar problem http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/219/5914

Comment: [Would this work?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7959941/967168)

Comment: @mcaleaa not straight answer, but may help a bit, thanks.

Comment: @FelixEve this does not answer how to move from `temporary://` to `public://` - and that's my main concern now. Will need to figure it out.

Comment: If you are able to pass a file from form callback to validation callback, then I am sure that in you submit callback you can catch it, move it to any distination as `managed` or `unmanaged` file. There are multiple functions that can provide this (you know them better than me): [file_save_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7), [system_retrieve_file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_retrieve_file/7) and so on.. Rececntly I did something like this without any problem (but i did it without plupload)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't really checked all links in this email but I have used Plupload very extensively and worked very well.

```
<?php 


  $form['upload'] = array(
    '#type' => 'plupload',
    '#title' => '',
    '#description' => t('Maximum file size allowed: 10MB'),
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('zip rar 7z odt doc docx xls xlsx png jpg pdf rtf txt'),
    ),
    '#plupload_settings' => array(
        'runtimes' => 'html5,flash', // Also consider the order of technologies.
        'chunk_size' => '10mb',
        'unique_names' => TRUE,
        'flash_swf_url' => file_create_url(_plupload_library_path() . '/js/plupload.flash.swf'),
      ),
    );


  return $form;


  // Submit handler:
  //function ..._submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!empty($form_state['values']['upload'])) {
    $form_state['uploaded_files'] = quotes_file_save_files($form_state['values']['upload']);
  }

  // }


function quotes_file_save_files($files) {
  $saved_files = array();
  $scheme = 'private://'; // Change to "public://" if you want to move to public files folder.
  foreach ($files as $uploaded_file) {
    if ($uploaded_file['status'] == 'done') {
      $source = $uploaded_file['tmppath'];
      $destination = file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize($scheme . $uploaded_file['name']);
      $destination = file_unmanaged_move($source, $destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
      $file = plupload_file_uri_to_object($destination);
      file_save($file);
      // Check the $file object to see if all necessary properties are set. Otherwise, use file_load($file->fid) to populate all of them.
      // $file = file_load($file->fid);
      $saved_files[] = $file;
    }
  }

  return $saved_files;
}


?>
```

I think the point is, plupload does not save the files to the managed files folder by default, but populates all the data in the $form_state array for you to process and save.

Edit: In relation to the other answer that mentions file object's status should be permanent. I'm sure you already know that the status must be 1. But `plupload_file_uri_to_object` function sets the $file object's status to 1, so it's not done in the example.

Good luck!

Comment: Needed to change to `$saved_files[] = file_load($file->fid);` to get file object properly populated with mime, names, et cetera, so I could pass it for validation. But it seems it'll work.

Comment: @Molot file_save() should update the $file object, just like node_save(), right? Unless the extra stuff are added in a hook, $file object should contain everything it just wrote to the database.

Comment: @AyeshK I assumed the same. But no. I did `kpr($file)` just after `file_save($file);` in `quotes_file_save_files($files)` and only `fid` was filled properly. I don't think re-loading should be needed. Sadly, it was needed. I wasted pretty much time trying to find out why, but ultimately I don't think I care as long as I have a working workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated the answer and added a comment about this.

Comment: @Molot did you get this working? I'm trying to save plupload files in a node from a custom form.

Answer (score 1):

I did a multiple gallery plugin that integrated with Ubercart and allowed users to upload multiple images with Plupload, per each attribute option.

Below is the part of the code that I used for uploading files. It goes in the `_submit()` handler function. The files were saved in the managed files table as permanent files and then were listed in orderable table view.

```
// Upload files.
foreach ($element['images']['#value'] as $uploaded_file) {
  $source = $uploaded_file['tmppath'];
  $filename = filefield_sources_clean_filename($uploaded_file['name'], array());
  // Move the file to a temporary destination using final base file name.
  $temp_destination = file_stream_wrapper_uri_normalize('temporary://' . $filename);
  $temp_filepath = file_unmanaged_move($source, $temp_destination, FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
  // Save the files to their final destination.
  if ($file = filefield_sources_save_file($temp_filepath, array(), 'public://your-path/' . $form['nid']['#value'] . '/')) {
    $file->oid = $element['oid']['#value'];
    // Set status to 1, meaning this is a permanent file and should not be
    // cleaned up upon cron run. IMPORTANT!
    $file->status = 1;
    file_save($file);
  }
  else {
    drupal_set_message(t('An error occurred during upload. Please try again.'));
  }
}
```

**Important**
You must set `$file->status = 1`, otherwise the file will be treated as temporary file and will be deleted upon next cron run.

If you need more code/working example, let me know and I'll clean the custom module a bit and post it.

Hope this helps.